# 標準のrandomモジュールとnumpy.randomの違い

Tags: python, numpy

pythonを使用して乱数を生成したいのですが、調べたところ標準のrandomというモジュールとnumpy.randomを使用する方法があるようなのですが、乱数生成における両者の違いは何でしょうか？

Answer (score 7):

Python標準の`random`と`numpy.random`は、どちらも擬似乱数を生成するもので、乱数生成器としてメルセンヌツイスタ（Mersenne Twister）を使っています。メルセンヌツイスタは、高速に統計的には問題のない疑似乱数を作成することができます。ただし、線形漸化式によって生成されるため予測可能なので、セキュリティ目的で使用する場合は、`secrets`モジュールを使用することが推奨されています。

Python ドキュメント [9.6. random --- 擬似乱数を生成する](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/library/random.html)
Numpy Doc [Random sampling (numpy.random)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/routines.random.html)

標準の`random`も`C`言語で作成されているため処理速度の方も変わりません。NumpyやPandasのように配列を使う場合は、`numpy.random`の方を使ったほうが`np.random.random(1000)`のように乱数の配列が簡単に作成できるので便利だし、配列の処理は高速です。一方、配列を使わない場合には、わざわざ`numpy`をインポートして使う必要もなく標準の`random`を使えばいいと思います。参考までにJupyterでの処理時間を載せておきます。

```
%%timeit
a = 0
for i in range(10000):
  a += random.random() 

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 ms per loop

%%timeit
a = 0
for x in np.random.random(10000):
  a += x

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 ms per loop
```

なお英語版にはこれと同じような質問 [Differences between numpy.random and random.random in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029993)があり、両者の違いは、`numpy.random.seed()`はスレッドセーフではないが、`random.random.seed()`の方はスレッドセーフであると書かれていますが、Pythonのドキュメントには以下のように書かれているので、`random.random.seed()`も複数のスレッドで使用する場合には注意が必要です。

> 9.6.6. 再現性について¶
>
> 疑似乱数生成器から与えられたシーケンスを再現できると便利なことがあります。シード値を再利用することで、複数のスレッドが実行されていない限り、実行ごとに同じシーケンスが再現できます。

Answer (score 0):

こちらの記事によると、大量に乱数を生成して処理を実行する場合にはnumpyのほうが高速であるようです。
https://qiita.com/yubais/items/bf9ce0a8fefdcc0b0c97

Answer (score 0):

こんな記事もあるのでご参考までに
乱数の発生個数に大きな違いがあるようですね
http://python-remrin.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2017/04/26/233717

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！　回答の際には、単に外部へのリンクを貼るだけでなく、その重要な部分を簡単にまとめて回答文に含めるようにしてください。リンク切れしてしまった場合、せっかくのご回答の意味が無くなってしまうからです。回答文下の「編集」から自由に追記できますので、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: また、user29851 さんは user29850 さんと同じ方でしょうか？　もしそうであれば、[こちらのページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)からアカウントを統合できますのでお試しください。今回2つの回答が投稿されていますが、内容的に1つにまとめるのが良いように思います。アカウントが1つになれば一方の回答を編集することで内容をまとめることができます。