# 標準のrandom.shuffleとnumpy.random.shuffleの結果の違いについて

Tags: python, numpy, random

以前に「[標準のrandomモジュールとnumpy.randomの違い](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47782/%E6%A8%99%E6%BA%96%E3%81%AErandom%E3%83%A2%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A8numpy-random%E3%81%AE%E9%81%95%E3%81%84)」について質問されていることは承知しています。また、その回答で計算速度の違いによるものとの認識をしております。

今回は、標準のrandom.shuffleとnumpy.random.shuffleの「結果の違い」について質問させていただきたいです。

2D arrayのRowをShuffleするだけのコードで、自分では理解できないことが発生しました。
まずサンプルコードを提示して、質問を後に記述させていただきます。

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

import numpy as np
import random

T1 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]];
T2 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]];

T1 = np.array(T1);
T2 = np.array(T2);

for i in range(0, 10):
    print ("trial:", i)
    print ("T1:", T1[0], T1[1], T1[2], T1[3], T1[4])
    np.random.shuffle(T1)
    print ("T1_np_random:", T1[0], T1[1], T1[2], T1[3], T1[4])

    print ("T2:", T2[0], T2[1], T2[2], T2[3], T2[4])
    random.shuffle(T2)
    print ("T2_random:", T2[0], T2[1], T2[2], T2[3], T2[4])
    print ();
```

このコードでは、5x2の2D arrayを２個(T1, T2)用意しています。
この２つのarrayに対して、それぞれrandom.shuffleとnp.random.shuffleを10回行います。
shuffleする度に結果を表示するだけのコードです。

randomを使いますので、毎回結果が違いますが、以下に一例をお示しします。

```
trial: 0
T1: [1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8] [ 9 10]
T1_np_random: [ 9 10] [7 8] [3 4] [5 6] [1 2]
T2: [1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8] [ 9 10]
T2_random: [1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [1 2] [5 6]      <- [1 2][5 6]に置き換わっている？

trial: 1
T1: [ 9 10] [7 8] [3 4] [5 6] [1 2]
T1_np_random: [1 2] [7 8] [3 4] [ 9 10] [5 6]
T2: [1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [1 2] [5 6]
T2_random: [1 2] [1 2] [5 6] [5 6] [3 4]

trial: 2
T1: [1 2] [7 8] [3 4] [ 9 10] [5 6]
T1_np_random: [5 6] [ 9 10] [1 2] [7 8] [3 4]
T2: [1 2] [1 2] [5 6] [5 6] [3 4]
T2_random: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [5 6] [1 2]　　　<- [1 2]に置き換わっている？

trial: 3
T1: [5 6] [ 9 10] [1 2] [7 8] [3 4]
T1_np_random: [ 9 10] [5 6] [7 8] [3 4] [1 2]
T2: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [5 6] [1 2]
T2_random: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]

trial: 4
T1: [ 9 10] [5 6] [7 8] [3 4] [1 2]
T1_np_random: [ 9 10] [3 4] [1 2] [5 6] [7 8]
T2: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]
T2_random: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]

trial: 5
T1: [ 9 10] [3 4] [1 2] [5 6] [7 8]
T1_np_random: [3 4] [5 6] [ 9 10] [1 2] [7 8]
T2: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]
T2_random: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]

trial: 6
T1: [3 4] [5 6] [ 9 10] [1 2] [7 8]
T1_np_random: [ 9 10] [1 2] [7 8] [3 4] [5 6]
T2: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]
T2_random: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]

trial: 7
T1: [ 9 10] [1 2] [7 8] [3 4] [5 6]
T1_np_random: [3 4] [ 9 10] [7 8] [1 2] [5 6]
T2: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]
T2_random: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]

trial: 8
T1: [3 4] [ 9 10] [7 8] [1 2] [5 6]
T1_np_random: [1 2] [3 4] [7 8] [5 6] [ 9 10]
T2: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]
T2_random: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]

trial: 9
T1: [1 2] [3 4] [7 8] [5 6] [ 9 10]
T1_np_random: [7 8] [5 6] [ 9 10] [1 2] [3 4]
T2: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]
T2_random: [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2] [1 2]
```

結果の中にもお示ししましたが、trial 0(一回だけshuffleした状態)では、shuffleをするだけでなく[7 8] [ 9 10]が[1 2][5 6]に置き換わっています。またtrialごとに置き換わりが起る時と起こらない時があります。
random.shuffleを使ったT2は、最終的には全て同じエレメントに置き換わっています。

このエラー（？）は、標準のrandomモジュールとnumpy.randomの計算速度の違いだけは説明できないと思います。

私の質問ですが、

1. 単純にnumpy.arrayを(numpyではない)random.shuffleを行うことは避けるべきでしょうか？
2. なぜこのようなエラーが出る原因は何でしょうか？

もし誰か説明できる方がおられましたら、ご教授をお願いします。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

原因は `T2` が 2次元の `numpy.ndarray` 型インスタンスだからです。

`random.shuffle()` のソースコードは以下になります。

[cpython/random.py at 3.6](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/random.py#L263)

```py
def shuffle(self, x, random=None):
    """Shuffle list x in place, and return None.
    Optional argument random is a 0-argument function returning a
    random float in [0.0, 1.0); if it is the default None, the
    standard random.random will be used.
    """

    if random is None:
        randbelow = self._randbelow
        for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
            # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
            j = randbelow(i+1)
            x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
    else:
                  :
```

操作としては `x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]` になります(tuple unpacking)。これを `T2` に対して行ってみます。

```py
>>> T2 = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
>>> T2 = np.array(T2)
>>> type(T2)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> T2
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])
>>> T2.shape
(5, 2)

>>> T2[0], T2[1] = T2[1], T2[0]
>>> T2
array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

`T2[0]` の値と `T2[1]` の値を交換する際に、内部では作業領域(一時変数)が確保されて `T2[0]` の値がコピーされるのですが、この場合は `T2[0]` が `numpy.ndarray` 型のインスタンスなので `T2[0]` への参照(のコピー)が割り当てられる事になります(shallow copy)。

```
## reference
>>> T2 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])
>>> v = T2[0]  ## assignment with shallow copy
>>> v
array([1, 2])
>>> T2[0] = T2[1]
>>> T2[0]
array([3, 4])
>>> v
array([3, 4])

## numpy's swap array items
>>> T2 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]])
>>> T2[[0, 1]] = T2[[1, 0]]
>>> T2
array([[ 3,  4],
       [ 1,  2],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

上記の様に `numpy.ndarray` での要素の swap 操作を行なうと想定通りの結果になります。

> 1. 単純にnumpy.arrayを(numpyではない)random.shuffleを行うことは避けるべきでしょうか？

はい、多次元の `numpy.ndarray` 型インスタンスに `random.shuffle()` を使用するのは避けるべき、となります。1次元(いわゆる `vector`)であれば `ndarray` の要素は scalar になるので上記の様な問題は発生しないのですけれども。

Comment: 大変丁寧な解説、ありがとうございます！

shuffle機能はswap(x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i])を使っていることは予想できましたが、そこにnumpy.ndarrayを入れた時shallow copyになっているとは知りませんでした。今まではshuffleは一度しか使わなかったので、大きな2d arrayでは問題大きくならず、気がつきませんでした。今回たまたまshuffle毎に細かな計算をする必要性があり、何度もshuffleした時に計算が破綻してことから気がつきました。大変勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。